# How can i use discord py to pin an image from a user with a specific role in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

is it possible to have my bot pin an image uploaded to a set channel from users with admin roles ?

this is what I've came up with so far

````py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == "160319785840672768" and message.channel.id == "802523353964609566":
        return

    if message.content.startswith('pin'):
        await message.pin()```
````

Comment: ID are ints not strings. Also, you probably want to use a command. It's not clear if you want to pin the message with the "pin" prefix or a referenced message. Please add more info to your post

Comment: Could you just further elaborate? It's still unclear what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to implement feature in the bot that would pin any image posted in a specific channel by users with a specific role , say one of the server admins uploads an image in the image channel , i would like the bot to pin that image automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to make it work

`attachments` is what was needed for the bot to pin the images
`channel.id`  and `author.id`  are the conditions in needed for the bot to only pin when a specific user uploads an attachement to a specific channel

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user:
        return

    if message.attachments and message.author.id == 160319785840672768 and message.channel.id == 802523353964609566 : # by adding this the bot only pins the messages from a specific user 
        await message.pin()
```